# React native font size not scaling

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a complex layout with text and images on iOS which supports iPhone 5s.
If there is a `Text` with style as `fontSize: 15` which looks alright on 5s but when i run it on iPhone 7 the font doesn't scale. Ideally the font should have scaled according to width and size of the phone since the `fontSize` in React native is unitless. So the font should look alright but all the fonts are very small on a bigger iPhone screen ( like iPhone 7, iPhone Plus, iPhone 8, iPhone 8 plus or iPhone X)

I have tried using `flex: 1` but it doesn't work.
Any suggestions as to how i can solve this issue?